# WordPress Multisite switch_to_blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I using WordPress multisite and I have a script not tied to a theme nor a plugin:

```
$blog_id = (isset($_REQUEST['site']) ? $_REQUEST['site'] : 5) ;
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
echo get_option('blogname');
```

Above does not work it defaults to 1 and if I echo $blog_id it outputs the correct value. The code below works blog_id is hard coded

```
switch_to_blog(10);
echo get_option('blogname');
```

I need to be able to change the blog_id on the fly

Comment: So what you are saying is that the $_REQUEST['site'] variable is invisible/empty? Thus it defaults to one? Did you var_dump($_REQUEST['site']) to make sure it's going through properly?

Comment: I tried setting $blog_id = 10.. I also tried casting it to int

Comment: There should not be a problem with something as simple as `$blog_id = 10;`

Comment: When I run echo get_current_blog_id(); it gives the correct ID which indicates that switch was made but echo get_option('blogname'); is still giving the wrong data.. hard coding the blog_id works

Comment: I found a solution:: switch_to_blog($_REQUEST['site']); must be the first thing on the page.. if $_REQUEST['site'] is not set it will default to site 1.. setting the $blog_id above switch_to_blog breaks it... hope this helps someone else out there.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, turns out you are not allowed to use $blog_id as it is used by wordpress,  change the name of the variable and the problem goes away.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer!